# How can I send message from one node to multiple nodes in OMNET++?

Tags: c++, performance, networking, simulation, omnet++

I have a network where I want a node to broadcast a messages to 5 nodes at once.. but I can't do it because there's one output gate and one input gate only.

secondly, I want to send multiple messages simultaneously, Like in this picture I want messages to be sent in the two subnetworks.

[Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDiMR.png)

**Here's my NED file**

```
package simulationnetwork;


network my_network
{
    @display("bgb=757,458,#80FF00;bgi=background/terrain,s");
    types:
        simple Node
        {
            gates:
                input innerport;
                output outerport;
                
               
        }

    submodules:
        node1: Node {
            @display("p=30,58");
        }
        node2: Node {
            @display("p=249,58");
        }
        node3: Node {
            @display("p=330,165");
        }
        node4: Node {
            
            
            @display("p=182,193");
        }
        node: Node {
            @display("p=155,377");
        }
        node5: Node {
            
            @display("p=275,291");
        }
        node6: Node {
            @display("p=451,311");
        }
    connections:
        node1.outerport --> node2.innerport;
        node2.outerport --> node3.innerport;
        node3.outerport --> node4.innerport;
        node4.outerport --> node1.innerport;
        node5.outerport --> node6.innerport;
        node6.outerport --> node.innerport;
        node.outerport --> node5.innerport;
}
```

**and here's my CC file**

```
#include <omnetpp.h>

using namespace omnetpp;

class Node: public cSimpleModule

{

protected:
    void initialize() override;
    void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override;

};

Define_Module(Node);
void Node:: initialize()
{
    if(strcmp("node1",getName())==0)
    {
        cMessage *msg = new cMessage("nodetable!,location");
        send(msg,"outerport");

    }





}

void Node::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    send(msg,"outerport");



}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you need more gates, you should use gate vectors i.e. `input innerport[]`
2. to broadcast, create copies (using `dup()`) and send them out on different gates using a for loop.

As you are a beginner, I highly recommend going through the [Tictoc tutorial](https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/part4/) which covers exactly the topic you are interested here.